# Web page's text is cutting off in browser

Tags: css, scroll

I recently imported CSS Bootstrap into my website, so that I could add a toolbar to it.  All went well, except that the text of my website now cuts off at the bottom.  I set the overflow of the body to scroll, to no avail. The website scrolls a little bit, but then the scroll bar stops before the end of the content.  If you zoom out on the browser, you can see all of the content.

The home page is a fairly long chunk of code, especially if I include the bootstrap, so I am not inclined to copy it here.  Have any of you encountered this, and do you remember / can you suggest how to rectify it?

Some of you suggested a link, and you're right.  Here is the page in question:  http://www.zipcodeconquest.com/home.php

Comment: It could be a million different things. Sounds like something on your existing site is conflicting with bootstrap class names. If you want further help we'll need code, even a link to a site will get you farther than nothing at all.

Comment: It could be anything, if the code is really long, spend some time creating a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) which'll help others help you. Quite alot of the time, the process of generating a sscce will help you fix the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, try changing your body height to "auto". Just a guess without seeing your code or a screenshot...

Answer (score 0):

look for a `white-space:nowrap` or `white-space:pre` property. Your container might have one of these styles and forces your text content to be displayed in a way that overlap it.